# Which xcode version can used for MAC 10.5.8?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am newbie to to xcode framework. My mac system has leopard operting system ,10.5.8. I have xcode installed version 3.0 .Can i update it to latest xcode 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Xcode 4.x is available as a free download for Lion (via the Mac App Store).  The latest version of Xcode 3.x is still available as a free download, though it may not be suitable with Leopard.

Edit: I meant to also say that for 10.5.8, you'll need to find out the last suitable version of Xcode.  Sorry I don't know that as I'm on 10.6; someone else could chime in.